# How to version control the JIRA changes?

Tags: jira

I asked the following two questions in JIRA Answers, but got no reply so far:

[Question 1](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12267539/how-to-move-changes-from-development-to-production)

[Question 2](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12267197/how-shall-i-version-my-design-so-we-can-rollback)

Basically my question is what's the best way to make changes in a JIRA production environment.

Comment: I don't know if it does versioning as such, but this add-on appears that it could help with the staging->production deployment part: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.botronsoft.jira.configurationmanager

Answer (score 0):

This will be rather general answer, but this is how I do it:

- I avoid modifying JIRA production files. When I need it (e.g. mail templates), I keep them under source control along with plugin in 'deploy' directory which mimics JIRA directory structure so it is possible to grap it and deploy it with copy&paste
- I frequently use javascript to decorate screens with custom behavior
- Schema changes, custom fields and other meta data are all created in code
- Keep everything in plugin and leverage plugin versioning system. Plugin should be able to check whether there is everything it needs and when not it should be able to upgrade incrementally.
- For JIRA configuration - this is the same, plugin should check whether it has everything it needs, but you can also keep configuration changes in some excel file and have it under source control

My aproach is to have everything possible in source control and modify production files only when absolutely necessary. Do as much in code as possible.